# How to use variables with Azure CLI

Tags: azure, azure-cli

I am trying to use variable in azure CLI like we used in powershell.

In powershell we define variable as follows

```
$LOCATION = value
```

And used it in command as follows

```
az group create --name foo --location $LOCATION
```

**What I have tried :-**

I have tried to find it out in Microsoft documentation

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/get-started-with-azure-cli?view=azure-cli-latest

but I did not get any information about that.

**Question :-**

1. How we can define variable in azure CLI?(like powershell)
2. How we can used it in command?(like powershell)

**Note:-** I have installed azure CLI at my local.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The easiest way to pass `variables` to any CLI command is by using `environment variables`

> An environment variable is a variable whose value is set outside the
> program, typically through a functionality built into the operating
> system or microservice. An environment variable is made up of a
> name/value pair, and any number may be created and available for
> reference at a point in time.

Below you can find examples in Bash and CMD:

**Bash**-

Set new environment variable-

```sh
export LOCATION=westeurope
```

Print the environment variable-

```sh
echo ${LOCATION}
```

AZ CLI example-

```sh
az group create --name foo --location ${LOCATION}
```

**CMD-**

Set new environment variable-

```sh
set LOCATION=westeurope
```

Print the environment variable-

```sh
echo %LOCATION%
```

AZ CLI example-

```sh
az group create --name foo --location %LOCATION%
```

Answer (score 1):

It is the same way you do it in powershell,

To assign a value

```
sajeetharan@Azure:~$ LOCATION="eastus"
```

To check value is set,

```
sajeetharan@Azure:~$ echo $LOCATION
eastus
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
New-Variable -Name "location" -Visibility Public -Value "eastus"
```

Answer (score 0):

### Azure Cloud Shell

**Assignment**: use double quotes if you are assigning a long string (`export` is not needed):

> AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net;AccountName=MYACCNAME;AccountKey=MYACCKEY"

**Usage**: invoke/surround it with `${}`, example:

- checking Storage Queue messages:

  ```
  az storage message peek \
    --connection-string ${AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING} \
    --queue-name MYQUEUE
  ```
- printing:

  ```
  echo ${AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING}
  ```